# How to check if a user has voted for a celebrity Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As per my requirements, I need to vote for all celebrity but if I voted for a particular celebrity it should not allow to vote for the same celebrity for 24 hours.

Vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :celebrity_id, :user_id

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :celebrity, counter_cache: true
end
```

Celebrity.rb

```
class Celebrity < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :gender, :category_id, :image, :votes_count
validates_presence_of :name
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
has_many :votes
end
```

My Controller:

```
def vote
@celebrities = Celebrity.find(params[:id])
if current_user.votes.present?
  if current_user.votes.last.updated_at < Time.now - 24.hours
    @vote = current_user.votes.build(celebrity_id: @celebrities.id, :id => params[:vote])        
    @vote.save
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to ranking_screen_url }
    format.json { render json: @vote, status: :created }
  end
else
  @vote = current_user.votes.build(celebrity_id: @celebrities.id, :id => params[:vote])     
  @vote.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to ranking_screen_url }
    format.json { render json: @vote, status: :created }
  end
end
end
```

Instead of checking `current_user.votes.present?` I need to check the user has voted for the celebrity_id in votes table. Can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if current_user.votes.present?
```

Here you are checking if a user has made any votes. I think you should be fetching the user vote of a specific celebrity. Like

```
@celebrity = Celebrity.find(params[:id])
@vote = current_user.votes.where(celebrity_id: @celebrity.id).first

if @vote
  if @vote.updated_at < (Time.now - 24.hours)
    # update count here
  else
else

end
```